# add and delete input submitted values to and from select element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xhtml

i want to create the functions to add and delete the submitted values to and from a text area.

as you see in the picture below, i have the last name first name and telephone and when i click add the values get added to the select area on the left. then if i choose someone from that select area and click delete, the selected option must get deleted.

any help will be highly appreciated. 
Best regards.

[take a look at an image example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7qVW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to remove selected option from select control

```
var x=document.getElementById("mySelect");
x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
```

check w3school : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp
after this clear the fields last name first name and telephone

Answer (score 0):

it was actually pretty easy..

i managed to do what i need with this function..

```
  function addSnow()
{
var addlast = document.snowForm.last.value;
var addfirst = document.snowForm.first.value;
var addphone = document.snowForm.phone.value;
var sum = addlast + " " + addfirst + " " + addphone;

var addnew = document.getElementById("selectSnow");
var newOpt = new Option(sum , sum);
addnew.options[addnew.options.length] = newOpt;
}
```

and this one is my form

```
<form name="snowForm">

    <select style="float:left;margin-right:5px;" name="selname" id="selectSnow" size="10">
        <option value="start">Group Members</option>
    </select>


    <table>
        <tr><td><input type="button" value="Add Snowboarder" onClick="addSnow()"/></td><td><input type="button" onclick="delSnow()" value="Delete Snowboarder"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last name:</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="last" size="15"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>First name:</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="first" size="15"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Telephone:</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="phone" size="15"/></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

but i now have another problem.. i want to fill the input gaps with the first name last name and telephone that will match with the person i will pick from the select area.
how would i be able to do something like this?